# What characteristics should a bucket have to be suitable for a mash tun?

Tags: mash, mash-tun, bucket, equipment

Does it need to have anything special or any food-grade bucket would do?

Answer (score 4):

Any food grade bucket will do, but keep in mind that the plastic will asborb flavors.  So don't use a pickle bucket (etc.) unless you want pickle-beer.

Comment: You can rectify these types of buckets by filling them with warm water and an entire box of baking soda.  A good long soak will clean up any bucket.

Answer (score 3):

As an extract brewer planning to start going all-grain sometime soon, I can't answer from experience.  But my plan is to start by buying a cooler to use as a mash tun.  You can use a bucket, but without any insulation you'll have a hard time maintaining the 150-158F required for a good mash.  I plan to build mine from one of those big job site drink coolers - they're made from food grade plastic and can help to maintain the temperature for an hour.

Comment: I recommend you use a rectangular cooler.  You get more volume for your money and they're easier to use due to a larger opening.  See www.dennybrew.com and https://www.homebrewersassociation.org/how-to-brew/advanced/how-to-brew-beer/#all-grain

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you buy a stainless steel barrel for wine and wrap it with any kind of insulation. They are not very expensive and they will not release any off flavours

I have one with a volume of 60 liters and i can easily make 50 liter batches with it.

Cheers